# Able to connect to site over https but NOT http?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, subdomain

so I'm currently in the process of setting up my Server.
A central part in this is that I want to host my Team Foundation Server there. I was able to configure it so it uses SSL/HTTPS and so far all is working fine. I can access the portal as I'm expecting.
The problem now is, I would also like to set up a redirect from http to the https version of the site and this isn't working apparently.

The site in question is
https://tfserver.marcusscholle.com/
Obviously you can't log in but you should see the login prompt at least.

However if I'm trying to access it over www.tfserver.marcusscholle.com I'm getting an error that the page isn't reachable. If looking at the redirected link it points to https://www.tfserver.marcusscholle.com/ which I assume is wrong.
I've Plesk installed on my Server and tried to set "Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS", but to no avail.

If I'm doing the same at my parent domain (marcusscholle.com), it works as expected, including the redirect from http to the https page.
So I would guess it's something specific about subdomains.

Someone has an idea on that?

EDIT: To give some additional information. The solutions posted most often, such as putting a rewrite rule into the web.config don't work in my case. Still getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in the browser. Should be said I'm only having two entries in the DNS settings of the subdomain, so I'm not sure if that could be an issue.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/search?q=redirect+from+http+to+https

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't really help much in my case. I'm using IIS so the whole .htaccess stuff doesn't fit. I edited my question a bit as I'm unsure if that's actually more a DNS issue.